# Interactive Legend onclick or mouseover - D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

I've been looking for a way to have my legend control my chart animation (similar to [NVD3 examples](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBarHorizontal.html)). I've run into a problem though - nested selections.

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(70,10)")
    ;

var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(colors);

legendRect.enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", w - 65)
   .attr("width", 10)
   .attr("height", 10)
   .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
   })
   .style("stroke", function(d) {
       return d[1];
   })
   .style("fill", function(d) {
       return d[1];
   });
```

I'm using a bit of a hack to do my animation. Basically setting `style` to `display: none`.
I want to be able to click on the rectangles and call the function. But putting a mouseover or onclick within `legendRect` doesn't work. The bars to animate are not children of the legend. **How can I call the function, or chain my function to my legend?**

```
function updateBars(opts) {
var gbars = svg.selectAll("rect.global");
var lbars = svg.selectAll("rect.local");
if (opts === "global") {
    gbars.style("display", "block") ;
    lbars.style("display", "none");
    gbars.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
};
if (opts === "local") {
    lbars.style("display", "block")
    ;
    gbars.style("display", "none");
    lbars.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", 1 / -xScale.rangeBand())
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
};
}
```

My **other obstacle is changing the fill color on click**. I want it to almost imitate a checkbox, so clicking (to deselect) would turn the fill white. I tried something similar as `.on("click",(".style" ("fill", "white")))`. But that is incorrect.

**[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/Hv867/10/)**. For some reason, the function isn't updating things on Fiddle. It works on my localhost though. Not sure the problem with that.

Comment: can you put up a fiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: Put one up. Although it's not working for some reason. But at least gives you a peak at the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure I understand you correctly, but if your first question is how to change element X when clicking on element Y, you need something along the lines of:

```
legendRect.on("click", function() {
  gbars.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style("display", "block")
    // etc...
}
```

As for changing the fill on click, try:

```
gbars.on("click", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("fill", "white");
}
```

Comment: that's pretty close to what I was wanting to do. But how would I handle what my function is doing. You see that I have an `if` block checking if I'm changing `global` or `local`. What would be a more effective way of doing this in your `legendRect.on("click", function...)`?

Comment: I copied all your code and it seems to be working fine. Of course you can accomplish the same thing in a number of different ways, but if the problem is solved, why bother?